# TCP socket client through proxy on nodejs

Tags: node.js, network-programming

I need to make tcp socket connection to smtp server. Is it possible to connect through proxy server on nodejs? Is there any npm modules available to use? I couldn't find any at all.

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('I am here!');
});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA: ' + data);

});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: why would you destroy the connection in the first data  handler?  data event could stream in multiple times.  And what are you proxying for?  This just looks like a regular client connection.

Comment: @Joe, I just updated the question. I need to connect to smtp server. The above is just an example, not a production code.

Comment: @Chamnap DId you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

`net.socket`, `tls.connect` and `dgram` have no proxy support.

The simplest way to use it with proxy is to replace some libc functions with `proxychains` or something similar.

```
var client = require('tls')
.connect(443, 'www.facebook.com', function() {
  console.log('connected');
  client.write('hello');
})
.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('received', data.toString());
})
.on('close', function() {
  console.log('closed');
});
```

> proxychains node fit.js

```
connected
received HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
closed
```

Comment: @AeroWang Did you found that package?

Answer (score 1):

I reworked [this](https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-tcp-proxy) article into something more modern, it only uses the built-in `net` package in NodeJS.

```js
const net = require('net')

class ProxyClient {
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config
    }

    async setup() {
        const { proxyClient } = this.config
        if (!proxyClient) {
            return
        }
        const { localPort, remoteHost, remotePort } = proxyClient
        console.info(`[ProxyClient] Starting ODBC proxy to ${remoteHost}:${remotePort} on local port ${localPort}...`)
        console.info('[ProxyClient] Opening service socket to remote host...')
        const serviceSocket = await new Promise(resolve => {
            const socket = new net.Socket()
            socket.connect(remotePort, remoteHost, () => resolve(socket))
        })
        console.info('[ProxyClient] Service socket to remote host opened.')
        console.info('[ProxyClient] Creating the local proxy server...')
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            const server = net.createServer(proxyServerSocket => {
                proxyServerSocket.on('data', message => {
                    serviceSocket.write(message)
                })
                serviceSocket.on('data', message => {
                    proxyServerSocket.write(message)
                })
            })
            server.listen(localPort, '0.0.0.0', () => resolve())
        })
        console.info('[ProxyClient] Local proxy server created.')
        console.info(`[ProxyClient] ODBC proxy to ${remoteHost}:${remotePort} on local port ${localPort} started successfully.`)
    }
}

module.exports = ProxyClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than 'net' you don't need another module to make a socket connect to a host through a proxy server as long at the proxy server supports HTTPS traffic.

1. Create a socket connection to the proxy server
2. Send an HTTP CONNECT message to inform the proxy server of the host and port you want to connect to
3. If the proxy server responds with an HTTP 200 response then the proxy server established a socket connection to your desired target and is now relaying the traffic between the sockets
4. If the proxy server responded with any HTTP response other than 200 then the connection was not established.

Even though this process starts with HTTP it doesn't mean it wouldn't work for SMTP traffic. The initial HTTP message is just used to negotiate the connection, after that its just raw traffic. A proxy server might look at the port or host you want to connect to and disallow it. For example, block connections to ports below 80 or below 443 such as port 25 so it really depends on the proxy server if the connection will be allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible with one of these NPM modules:

**[http-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-http-proxy-agent)**: An HTTP(s) proxy http.Agent implementation for HTTP endpoints

**[https-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent)**: An HTTP(s) proxy http.Agent implementation for HTTPS endpoints

**[pac-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-pac-proxy-agent)**: A PAC file proxy http.Agent implementation for HTTP and HTTPS

**[socks-proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-socks-proxy-agent)**: A SOCKS (v4a) proxy http.Agent implementation for HTTP and HTTPS

**HTTPS Proxy Example:**

```
var url = require('url');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

// HTTP/HTTPS proxy to connect to
var proxy = process.env.http_proxy || 'http://168.63.76.32:3128';
console.log('using proxy server %j', proxy);

// WebSocket endpoint for the proxy to connect to
var endpoint = process.argv[2] || 'ws://echo.websocket.org';
var parsed = url.parse(endpoint);
console.log('attempting to connect to WebSocket %j', endpoint);

// create an instance of the `HttpsProxyAgent` class with the proxy server information
var opts = url.parse(proxy);

var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(opts);

// finally, initiate the WebSocket connection
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint, { agent: agent });

socket.on('open', function () {
  console.log('"open" event!');
  socket.send('hello world');
});

socket.on('message', function (data, flags) {
  console.log('"message" event! %j %j', data, flags);
  socket.close();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Those above are http/https and websocket. Is it working a tcp socket client because I need to connect to smtp server.

Comment: @Chamnap it doesn't