# How to configure node.js (express.js) app behind proxy?

Tags: node.js, linux, express, proxy, passport.js

My node.js app (using express.js) needs to send https requests through my company's proxy.

I tried the following commands to add the proxy but it doesn't work :

```
sudo npm config set proxy http://proxyIP:proxyPORT
sudo npm config set https-proxy https://proxyIP:proxyPORT
```

I'm still having a timeout :

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 194.3.8.11:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1081:14)
```

Any help please ?
Many thanks

Comment: see that answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710542/tcp-socket-client-through-proxy-on-nodejs) it has been already asked thought...

Comment: @user3732793 it's not the same problem... I'm would like to know if there's any global proxy configuration for node.js app behind proxy

Comment: you could create your config file and read it to some options. as in the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect. search for "make a request to a tunneling proxy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

I used the package [global-tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel)
PS : this package depends on [tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel) package that you must update to version >=0.0.5