# How to make net.connect() requests via socks5 (or other) proxy?

Tags: node.js

From my understanding `net.connect(port[, host][, connectListener])` or `socket.connect(port[, host][, connectListener])` doesn't support proxy configuration. What would be the in app solution to use socks5 or ther proxy servers for net.connect/socket.connect?

Comment: You can look into this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710542/tcp-socket-client-through-proxy-on-nodejs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks-proxy-agent

Comment: @BipulJain that's not an in app solution.